# How can I directly draw an SKPath from SVG string on screen arbitrarily in SkiaSharp?

Tags: c#, svg, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am building an application which can send and receive skia sharp drawings. The SKPath is serialized into SVG format and sent. The receiving end then must deserialize and draw the SKPath from the SVG string. However, it seems impossible to do this outside the OnCanvasViewPaintSurface event.

I am currently trying to do this in the finger paint example in the Xamarin examples solution. The DrawTestLine method should draw a little freehand line I drew and serialized into SVG. In reality it runs with no exceptions but draws nothing on the screen.

Any help to get this to work is massively appreciated.

See my modifications below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

using TouchTracking;

using SkiaSharp;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;

namespace SkiaSharpFormsDemos.Paths
{
    public partial class FingerPaintPage : ContentPage
    {
        Dictionary<long, SKPath> inProgressPaths = new Dictionary<long, SKPath>();
        List<SKPath> completedPaths = new List<SKPath>();
        SKBitmap bitmap;

        SKPaint paint = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
            Color = SKColors.Blue,
            StrokeWidth = 10,
            StrokeCap = SKStrokeCap.Round,
            StrokeJoin = SKStrokeJoin.Round
        };

        public FingerPaintPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DrawTestLine();
        }

        private void DrawTestLine()
        {
            var svgPath = "M851.953 371.006L865.957 438.527L874.922 462.995L880.957 453.997L884.941 441.011L893.965 427.874L895.957 418.233L900.938 415.006L902.93 405.02L898.945 403.998";
            var testPath = SKPath.ParseSvgPathData(svgPath);
            bitmap = new SKBitmap(1920, 1080);// (int)canvasView.CanvasSize.Width, (int)canvasView.CanvasSize.Height);
            var canvas = new SKCanvas(bitmap);
            canvas.Clear();
            canvas.DrawPath(testPath, paint);
            canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
        }

        void OnTouchEffectAction(object sender, TouchActionEventArgs args)
        {
            switch (args.Type)
            {
                case TouchActionType.Pressed:
                    if (!inProgressPaths.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                    {
                        SKPath path = new SKPath();
                        path.MoveTo(ConvertToPixel(args.Location));
                        inProgressPaths.Add(args.Id, path);
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    break;

                case TouchActionType.Moved:
                    if (inProgressPaths.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                    {
                        SKPath path = inProgressPaths[args.Id];
                        path.LineTo(ConvertToPixel(args.Location));
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    break;

                case TouchActionType.Released:
                    if (inProgressPaths.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                    {
                        completedPaths.Add(inProgressPaths[args.Id]);
                        inProgressPaths.Remove(args.Id);
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    break;

                case TouchActionType.Cancelled:
                    if (inProgressPaths.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                    {
                        inProgressPaths.Remove(args.Id);
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
        {
            args.Surface.Canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0);

            SKCanvas canvas = args.Surface.Canvas;
            canvas.Clear();

            foreach (SKPath path in completedPaths)
            {
                canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
            }

            foreach (SKPath path in inProgressPaths.Values)
            {
                canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
            }
        }

        SKPoint ConvertToPixel(Point pt)
        {
            return new SKPoint((float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width * pt.X / canvasView.Width),
                               (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Height * pt.Y / canvasView.Height));
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: you are drawing the path on a new canvas that is not attached to your View

Comment: Great how do I attach it?

Comment: you already have an active canvas, why aren't you just doing this in `OnCanvasViewPaintSurface`?

Comment: I need to be able to do this any time not just when the page loads. Is there a way I can do that in OnCanvasViewPaintSurface?

Comment: call `InvalidateSurface`.  The canvas paints whenever it needs to, not just on page load

Comment: If you look at my code I'm doing that already but this does not work.

Comment: none of your SVG code is called from `OnCanvasViewPaintSurface`

Comment: Aha the penny dropped. Slow day for me today.

Comment: what is canvasView ? Where do I find this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

using TouchTracking;

using SkiaSharp;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;

namespace SkiaSharpFormsDemos.Paths
{
    public partial class FingerPaintPage : ContentPage
    {
        Dictionary<long, SKPath> inProgressPaths = new Dictionary<long, SKPath>();
        List<SKPath> completedPaths = new List<SKPath>();
        SKBitmap bitmap;

        SKPaint paint = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
            Color = SKColors.Blue,
            StrokeWidth = 10,
            StrokeCap = SKStrokeCap.Round,
            StrokeJoin = SKStrokeJoin.Round
        };

        SKPath testPath = SKPath.ParseSvgPathData("M851.953 371.006L865.957 438.527L874.922 462.995L880.957 453.997L884.941 441.011L893.965 427.874L895.957 418.233L900.938 415.006L902.93 405.02L898.945 403.998");

        public FingerPaintPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DrawTestLine();
        }

        private void DrawTestLine()
        {
            canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
        }

        void OnTouchEffectAction(object sender, TouchActionEventArgs args)
        {
            switch (args.Type)
            {
                case TouchActionType.Pressed:
                    if (!inProgressPaths.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                    {
                        SKPath path = new SKPath();
                        path.MoveTo(ConvertToPixel(args.Location));
                        inProgressPaths.Add(args.Id, path);
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    break;

                case TouchActionType.Moved:
                    if (inProgressPaths.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                    {
                        SKPath path = inProgressPaths[args.Id];
                        path.LineTo(ConvertToPixel(args.Location));
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    break;

                case TouchActionType.Released:
                    if (inProgressPaths.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                    {
                        completedPaths.Add(inProgressPaths[args.Id]);
                        inProgressPaths.Remove(args.Id);
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    break;

                case TouchActionType.Cancelled:
                    if (inProgressPaths.ContainsKey(args.Id))
                    {
                        inProgressPaths.Remove(args.Id);
                        canvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
        {           
            bitmap = new SKBitmap((int)canvasView.CanvasSize.Width, (int)canvasView.CanvasSize.Height);
            var canvas = new SKCanvas(bitmap);
            canvas.Clear();
            canvas.DrawPath(testPath, paint);

            args.Surface.Canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0);

            canvas.Clear();

            foreach (SKPath path in completedPaths)
            {
                canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
            }

            foreach (SKPath path in inProgressPaths.Values)
            {
                canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
            }
        }

        SKPoint ConvertToPixel(Point pt)
        {
            return new SKPoint((float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Width * pt.X / canvasView.Width),
                               (float)(canvasView.CanvasSize.Height * pt.Y / canvasView.Height));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is canvasView ? Where do I find this ?